# How to find index before the max-value index, idxmax()?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with CountryName as the index and values for their GDP as a column. I'm trying to find the index (the country name) that comes before the country with the max GDP.

```
CountryName   GDP 
US             350
UK             370 
Australia      340 
Germany        500 
France         450
```

If i do, `df['GDP'].idxmax()` , it'll return `Germany`. But is there a simple way to return `Australia`? (the index before the max index).

Comment: @ayorgo He is not asking for the second highest value, but for the `index` value that is just before the max value.

Comment: Agree with Anthony Raymond. The question here is not a duplicate of "Pandas: Find index of the row with second highest value".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) method of dataframes can help you out in this situation.

```
# Initialize dataframe
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'CountryName': ['US', 'UK', 'Australia', 'Germany', 'France'],
    'GDP': [350, 370, 340, 500, 450],
})
df = df.set_index('CountryName')

# Get the index value of the row directly before the row with max 'GDP' value
target = df['GDP'].shift(-1).idxmax()
```

gives as result:

```
In [1]: target
Out[1]: 'Australia'
```

Comment: Thanks. this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.ndarray.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.argmax.html) and index the index:

```
res = df.index[df['GDP'].values.argmax() - 1]  # Australia
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CountryName': ['US', 'UK', 'Australia', 'Germany', 'France'], 'GDP': [350, 370, 340, 500, 450]})
print(df['CountryName'][df['GDP'].idxmax()-1])
# Australia
```

One thing I can see a problem in is if the highest `GDP` has index `0` which would return `CountryName` at position `-1` or the last country in the dataframe.

Comment: It didn't. Maybe cause CountryName is the index. It would work if it's a column, but I was trying to figure out a way to do it without having to convert it into a column and just working on the index. Thanks

Comment: Yup, you're right. My mistake; misunderstood the table.